# How to remove service application from Add/Remove Programs if it is no longer listed as a service?

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-xp, windows-installer, uninstallation

I had a windows installer install a service I created. I tested on my dev machine rather than a test machine. The application files no longer exist and the service does not show up in the list of Windows Services under Admin Tools. I am trying to remove the entry from the Add/Remove programs. I set the installer up with a custom action of uninstalling the service when the uninstaller is run.

Even with manually copying the files to the expected location and manually adding the service in to the list of services, the uninstaller fails. I can't manage to remove it from the list of add remove programs. How can I remove it from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

http://setupanddeployment.com/cleanup/installer-cleanup/

http://setupanddeployment.com/cleanup/installer-cleanup-update/

Comment: Yes, ended up going with Windows Installer Cleanup utility. Thanks for saving my bacon. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

All the [entries shown in the Add/Remove Programs panel are found in the Registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` -- you'll find your in a subkey named with a GUID (e.g. "{123409-adsf-1234...}") if it was installed from an MSI (in which case <strike>you probably want to re-run the MSI to remove cleanly</strike> *you really should use `msiexec /x {GUID}` to uninstall, or double-click the original MSI package and choose "Remove"*) or it could be any name if it was installed with another setup tool.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this because the component and feature registration information will still remain on the machine. Also, reinstalling the MSI for a clean removal is not really an option because Windows Installer uses reference counts for components installed by different packages.

Comment: Exactly...which is why I suggested that MSIs should only be uninstalled from the original or cached package--I'll correct the wording so it is more clear. Re-running the package, if installed, will usually prompt if you want to 'repair' or 'remove' (unless authored otherwise); fortunately, repairs and re-installs of an already-installed MSI will not increase the shared component refcounts.